# migrar un campo de una tabla a otra sin que sea clave primaria

Tags: mysql

Buenas, estoy diseñando una base de datos de venta.

Pero tengo un problema. Necesito que a la hora de insertar datos en mi tabla, se vea de la siguiente forma:

Tabla **detalle_venta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, la **id** de mi tabla **detalle_venta** tiene que viajar hasta mi tabla **venta** como clave foranea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en que para insertar datos en mi tabla **detalle_venta** el id no tiene que repetirse, por que esta como clave primaria, y solo como clave primaria puedo mandarlo a la otra tabla. Agradecería cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: No estoy seguro de entenderte. Una clave primaria no puede repetirse, pero una clave foranea sí, ese es su propósito: referenciar a otra clave tantas veces como sea necesario. En tu tabla "detalle_venta" no dices cual es la clave primaria, por el ejemplo que pones imagino que será la combinación de "id" e "id_articulo"; si es así en tu tabla "venta" (o la que sea intermedia si estableces relaciones n-n) tendrás que construir la clave foránea con la combinación de claves primarias.

Comment: No, solo tengo una clave primaria para cada tabla. Lo acabo de editar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"id_det_venta" en la tabla "detalle_venta" es clave primaria y no puede tener repetidos (así que no comprendo que es "id" en el ejemplo que pones al principio).

"id_det_venta" en "venta" es clave foránea, puede repetirse tanto como sea necesario; lo que indicas con esa relación es que cada "venta" tiene un sólo y único "detalle_venta" relacionado.

Si lo que quieres es que cada "venta" pueda tener varios "detalle_venta" relacionados debes tener una tabla intermedia que guarde esa relación.

Algo como:

```
tabla "venta_detalleVenta"
id_venta int(11)
id_det_venta int(11)
```

siendo ambos campos (`id_vent`a e `id_det_venta`) claves primarias en esa tabla.

Entonces, cada vez que quieras establecer la relación de una "venta" con un "detalle_venta" sólo tendrás que guardar ambas id en la tabla "venta_detalleVenta"; con tantos "detalle_venta" por "venta" como necesites.

Comment: Entonces la clave id_det_venta, siendo clave foranea y clave primaria a la vez en la tabla venta_detalleVenta, puede repetirse sus valores?

Comment: Pueden repetirse los valores, pero no la suma de los valores. Una clave primaria es única, en caso de ser un conjunto de campos sigue siendo única, pero los valores de cada campo no; quizá con un ejemplo quede mas claro, imagina que la tabla "venta_detalleVenta" tiene los siguientes valores para "id_venta" e "id_det_venta": (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), [...] Verás que "id_venta" tiene siempre el mismo valor, pero "id_det_venta" cambia; cada par debe ser único, pero en cualquier combinación. Así una "venta" podrá tener tantos "detalle_venta" como necesites.

Answer (score 1):

La PK (id_det_venta) de tu tabla detalle_venta debe ser FK en la tabla venta. De ese modo, cada venta tiene un detalle (ya que la FK es la PK de la otra tabla). Esto te garantiza la unicidad. En realidad no lo mandas a la otra tabla, sino que desde la tabla ventas hacés referencia a la PK de la tabla detalle_venta que hace de FK.